# How to change the function to limit its action to the id, class or selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a function written in jquery that copies the value of the checkbox to the textarea #msg

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        var output = "";
        $("input:checked").each(function() {
            output += $(this).val() + "";
        });
        
        $("#msg").val(output.trim());
    });
});
```

Clicking any checkbox on side copies of its value to the #msg field
How to reduce this effect that only checkboxes in the `<ul>` or a selected div operate in such a manner?

I want this:

```html
<ul>
    <input name="foo2" type="checkbox" value="Hello" id="tel_1">
    <label for="tel_1">Hello</label>
</ul>
```

To be copied to the `#msg` textarea and this :

```html
<input name="foo" value="123123123" id="tel_11" type="checkbox">
<label for="tel_11">Alan</label>
```

Not to be copied. I played with this :

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function()
```

And changed `input:checkbox` to `ul:input:checkbox` but I do not want to work.

Comment: Why do you have `<ul>` without `<li>` inside it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `id` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tel_1").click(function() {
        var output = "";
        output += $(this).val() + "";
        $("#msg").val(output.trim());
    });
});
```

Or if you want to exclude just `#tel_11` you could use `:not()` selector like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:checkbox:not('#tel_11')").click(function() {
        var output = "";

        $("input:checked:not('#tel_11')").each(function() {
            output += $(this).val() + "";
        });

        $("#msg").val(output.trim());
    });
});
```

**Update :**

If you have several `id`'s as you sain in the comment (answers example) you could use start with selector like `$("[id^='answer_'")` ans that will include all of your 18 answers, e.g :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id^='answer_'").click(function() {
        var output = "";
        output += $(this).val() + "";
        $("#msg").val(output.trim());
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if i have 18 checkboxes like tel_1? is there any other way to do it? like put all 18 #tel_x inside one div and make it works?

Comment: Yes you could use other selectors like start with `^` or end with `$` or contain, just specify the problem and i'll update my answer.

Comment: ok so let's say that i can change #tel_1 to #answer_1 and i'll habe 18 answers(so it won't me mix with #tel_11 as I give in my example) so i'll have #answer_1, #answer_2, ...., #answer_18.

Answer (score 1):

Use a selector that just matches checkboxes that are children of `<ul>`.

```
$("ul > :checkbox").click(function() {
    ...
});
```